# root password not getting saved

Tags: mysql, xampp

At some time or other I've change the root password to 'aaa'. Now I want to change it to 'bbb'.

I've tried doing this in xampp shell, using mysqladmin, using `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('bbb');` and it works until the next time I flush privileges or restart the server and it gets reset to 'aaa'.

'aaa' is obviously getting cached somewhere, but I can't for the life of me figure out where. Any suggestions?

Comment: check this: https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords

Comment: As stated: I know HOW to do it. I've done it before. But now no matter how many times I try, as soon as I flush or restart the server, it gets reset to it's previous state (even though the new value works until then).

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) article on dev.mysql.com. It states:

> If the ALTER USER statement fails to reset the password, try repeating the procedure using the following statements to modify the user table directly:
>
> `UPDATE mysql.user
>      SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
>      WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
>   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Solved my issue.